# click link and echo statement on next page?

Tags: php, hyperlink, echo

Hi i'm trying to think of a way that if a user clicks a certain link it takes them to a new page where only if the user has come from that parent link it will echo a statement on the newly opened page?

Is this possible and if so does anyone know how i could do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly but give this a try...
`HTTP_REFERER` could help you do this but it isn't really reliable.

```
<?php
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$referer_parse = parse_url($referer);

if($referer_parse['host'] == "yoursite.com" || $referer_parse['host'] == "www.yoursite.com") 
{
     //from expected page
     //echo here

} else {

     //not from expected page
     //do something else
}
?>
```

**NOTE**

This is a sample code showing the logic, you'll still need to modify this to fit your needs.

---

**INFO**

I would suggest trying to find a way/logic to implement it with the use of secret/session keys.

Good luck,
Madz

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly

```
<a href="abc.php?link=1">Link 1</a>
<a href="abc.php?link=2">Link 2</a>
<a href="abc.php?link=3">Link 3</a>
```

Then in **abc.php**

```
$link = $_GET['link']; // Don't forget to sanitize the data

if($link == 1)
{
  // user clicked Link 1
}
else if($link == 2)
{
  // user clicked Link 2
}
else if($link == 3)
{
  // user clicked Link 3
}
else
{
   // came from somewhere else; i.e. did not click the links
}
```